# Python process text files in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 10 text files in the same folder. I want to process each text file individually in a for loop.

```
def qwerty():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
       dicts = {}
       for words in f:
          split_words = reg.finditer(words)
          for line in split_words:
             group1 = line.group(1)
             if group1 not in dicts:
                dicts[group1] = 1
             else:
                dicts[group1] += 1 
     return dicts
```

This is my code to process the individual text file. How do I run a loop that would process all the text files I have one by one? So the amount of text files correspond to the number of iterations in the for loop.

Comment: Do these text file names follow a pattern? You could `from glob import glob` and then `for filename in glob("*.txt")`.

Comment: @tdelaney Hi, no the text file don't follow a name pattern

Comment: Do you want to process all files in that directory?

Comment: sorry they are all .txt files @tdelaney

Answer (score 2):

You may use `os` module to iterate over all the files in current directry and filter only the txt files as :

```
import os

for file_name in os.listdir("./"):
    if file_name.endswith(".txt"): # Add some other pattern if possible
        # Call your method here
```

Your current directory would contain some other files as well, which may not get filtered, So it would be a better idea to move the `txt` files to a separate location.

Comment: Apparently, these files don't have a .txt extension. Using `os.path.isfile` may be a good change.

Comment: But in the given snippet the OP was using `'file.txt'` which made me to assume that the text files have extension `.txt`

Comment: I made the same assumption in comments and was corrected. They don't follow a `*.txt` pattern. This will be the right answer... if we can get OP to tell us what rules to follow. Using `isfile` gets all files in the directory and that's the closest match to his description.

Comment: But `isFile` would be true for all files in current directory, It includes `.py, .pyc, .blah, .foo, .bar` and I don't guess it would do any good, However I have suggested to move the files to another directory and iterate over all the files in that directory.

Comment: But it would be false for subdirectories. OP has told us that "*.txt" doesn't work so you'll have to change something. All we know is there is a directory with files to process, so processing all of the files is apparently what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the files in a folder and use that in a for loop

```
import os
from glob import glob

def qwerty(folder_path="."):
    for filename in glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.txt")):
        ... do your processing
```